# Can I use two sets of variables in one foreach loop?

Tags: foreach, powershell-4.0

Is is possible to construct one single `foreach` loop that loops through using two separate sets of variables?

Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do - except this example lists two separate loops whereas I would like to set them up in one single loop.

```bsh
$Sites = @("https://www.google.com" , "https://duckduckgo.com")
$Site_names = @( "Google" , "DuckDuckGO")

foreach  ($element in $Sites) {
  Write-Host "`n`n"
  $element
  Write-Host "`n`n"
}

foreach ($name in $Site_names) {
  Write-Host "`n`n"
  $name
  Write-Host "`n`n"
}
```

There is other code to be used so the loop needs to be able to allow for multiple lines of code in the code block - so a single line solution if there is one isn't what I'm after. Also I didn't think using the pipeline would be workable (but I could certainly be wrong on that).

Two sets of variables: `$Sites` and `$Site_names`.

I would like one `foreach` loop that runs through and lists the site address and the site name with both values changing each time the loop is run.

- First run: reference the URL "https://www.google.com" and the site name "Google".
- Second run: reference the URL "https://duckduckgo.com" and the site name "DuckDuckGo".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two arrays of the same size you can simply use a `for` loop like this:

```bsh
for ($i=0; $i -lt $Sites.Count; $i++) {
  "{0}`t{1}" -f $Site_names[$i], $Sites[$i]
}
```

However, if the elements of your two arrays are correlated anyway, it would be better to use a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) instead:

```bsh
$Sites = @{
  'Google'     = 'https://www.google.com'
  'DuckDuckGo' = 'https://duckduckgo.com'
}

foreach ($name in $Sites.Keys) {
  "{0}`t{1}" -f $name, $Sites[$name]
}
```

Comment: I used the hash table & it worked perfectly!  When used in my actual longer script, on running it, it was printing the website address to screen so I just changed the screen text to black before the foreach loop starts and back to white just after it starts and that hid the url. AWESOME answer. Thanks very much @ansgarwiechers !!